# How to prove that $x^5-5$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt[3] 3) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

> How to prove that $x^5-5$ is irreducible over $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt[3] 3)? $

I came across this problem while solving another one and I dunno exactly how to proceed. I know by Eisenstein's criterion that $p_c(x)= x^5-5 $ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$. This gives me for instance that any field extension containing $\sqrt[5]5$ must be at least of degree  $5$, but since the degree of $K$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $6$, this won't help me to guarantee that $\sqrt[5] 5 \not \in K$.

Any further directions? thanks.

Comment: Well $Q(\sqrt[5]{5})$ would them be a subfield. Is that possible?

Comment: @Sorfosh I know that the answer is no beacuse $5$ does not divide $6$. But I still can't figure out why $p_c$ being reducible would imply that $Q(\sqrt[5]5)$ is a subfield. Would you mind completing your hint?

Comment: I am not sure where the confusion is. If $\sqrt[5]{5} \in Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3})$ then $Q(\sqrt[5]{5})$ must be a subfield of $Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3})$ by definition. It is the smallest field (with $Q$) that has $\sqrt[5]{5}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $p(x):=x^5-5$ (why do you need the unnecessary subscript $c$ anyway?).  If $p(x)$ is reducible over $K$, then $p(x)$ has a linear factor over $K$ or an irreducible quadratic factor over $K$.

In the case where $p(x)$ has a linear factor over $K$, it follows that $p(x)$ has a root in $K$.   Since $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $\sqrt[5]{5}$ is the unique real root of $p(x)$, it follows that $\sqrt[5]{5}\in K$, which you know why this is false.

In the case where $p(x)$ has an irreducible quadratic factor $q(x)\in K[x]$.  Since $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we must have
$$q(x)=(x-\omega\sqrt[5]{5})(x-\bar{\omega}\sqrt[5]{5})\,,$$
where $\omega$ is a primitive $5$-th root of unity.  This shows that the constant term $\sqrt[5]{25}$ of $q(x)$ is in $K$.  You probably know why $\sqrt[5]{25}$ is not in $K$.

> Here is a proof.  If $\sqrt[5]{25}$ is in $K$, then $\sqrt[5]{5}=\dfrac{(\sqrt[5]{25})^3}{5} \in K$.